# Circular solution of Kepler Problem

Tags: dynamical-systems, hamilton-jacobi-equation

How can I get a circular solution of the $2-$dimensional Kepler problem of the form

$$q=\exp(Kt)a$$

being

$$\exp(Kt)= \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(t) & \sin(t)\\
  -\sin(t) & \cos(t)\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

and $a$ a constant vector?

Don't know how to start.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sure this question is not self-contained. What is the Kepler problem? What is $a$ and $q$ and $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I got is:

Kepler Problem: (1) $\ddot{q}=\frac{-\mu}{||q||^3}q$

As we want a solution of the form $q=(cos(t)*a_1+sin(t)*a_2, -sin(t)*a_1+cos(t)*a_2)$, we simply look for its derivatives:

$\dot{q}=(-sin(t)*a_1+cos(t)*a_2, -cos(t)*a_1-sin(t)*a_2)$
$\ddot{q}=(-cos(t)*a_1-sin(t)*a_2, sin(t)*a_1-cos(t)*a_2)$

$||q||= ||a||= \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$

Substituing in (1) we find:
$||a||=\sqrt[3]{\mu}$

Taking $a_2=0$ we find a circular solution of the Kepler problem:
$$q=(\sqrt[3]{\mu}cos(t), -\sqrt[3]{\mu}sin(t)$$ which are cercles of radius $\sqrt[3]{\mu}$